# TypeScript compilation outside of project created with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, gruntjs, typescript

I have inherited a large LOB application that is built using TypeScript. The project has no reference paths in any of the files due to the fact it has been setup and created using Visual Studio 2013 - Visual Studio seems to have some magic where it will pick up the global TypeMaps itself. *scoff*.

The current build process has been to use Grunt to **copy** the compiled .js files (which are generated on save in Visual Studio) to a build directory - not actually compile them.

(to further reinforce this point, Grunt is **NOT** compiling any TypeScript).

This build process is now no longer acceptable as I am moving the application to a build through a Continuous Integration process, using Team City and Command Line tsc.exe/Grunt - so when the repository is checked out there are obviously no generated .js files in the project.

In its current state there is a host of compilation errors when trying to use Command Line tsc.exe/Grunt to compile the TypeScript files, I think due to the fact that the application is not using reference paths?

Does this mean I'm going to need to add all of the relevant reference paths to each file in the project?

Has anyone got any experience regarding this kind of setup and could point me in the right direction to manage these reference paths and build process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution has been found.

Using the Visual Studio configuration options in the grunt-ts task I have setup the task to specifically use the projects .csprog and TypeScript 1.4 compiler (we are locked into this compiler).

My configuration for the grunt-ts task:

```
    ts: {
        default: {
            vs: "Consortium.Client.Web.csproj",
            options: {
                compiler: "1.4/tsc"
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope on the off chance, this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

> In its current state there is a host of compilation errors when trying to use Command Line tsc.exe/Grunt to compile the TypeScript files, I think due to the fact that the application is not using reference paths

No. You should use a `tsconfig.json` which will create the *compilation context*.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/project.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when adding reference paths to the files the namespacing and "cannot find module" errors disappear (for the file thats been referenced). Also TypeScript 1.4 is in use which means tsconfig's aren't supported right?

Comment: `Also TypeScript 1.4 is in use which means tsconfig's aren't supported right` Yes. But then again neither is TypeScript 1.4. Not keeping the language up to date can be a bad idea. For context think back to C# `ArrayList` vs. `List<T>`

Comment: As much as I agree with you, this project isn't currently in a position to really go down the rabbit hole of updating the TypeScript compiler [breaking changes] - it's a large LOB application and the priority is the build process.

Comment: You can use the the latest compiler with old code bases mostly *just fine*

Comment: Ok I will attempt to update the TS compiler. But that doesn't explain how the namespacing issues disappear when adding reference paths? Is this not how tools such as grunt-ts compile TypeScript files?

Comment: As an update, upgrading the compiler to 1.7 was not a seamless transition. I have a little over 90 errors to work through.

Comment: @RichardWatts most of these were probably *actual errors in the code base* that were not caught previously. True?

Comment: Indeed but there are also lot of errors relating to external definition files. Ember being one of them.

Comment: ohhh ... ember is not very TypeScript friendly. Because it used to have its own `createClass` kind of API instead of supporting native JavaScript/TypeScript classes